# Play 8k video in wpf using mediaELement is freezing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, windows-media-player

I am using WPF mediaement to play video, so basically my app is downloading the video from server and stored in local system path. I will get a event then I will fetch the video using  path and play in mediaement.

xaml

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElementPlayer"/>
```

.cs code

```
 System.Drawing.Rectangle resolution = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
 MediaElementPlayer.Width = resolution.Width;
 MediaElementPlayer.Height = resolution.Height;
 MediaElementPlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
 MediaElementPlayer.Source = new Uri(videoPlayerModel.videoSourcePath);
```

Here I am facing a lag issue when I use video resolution more then 8k , below 8k all video are working fine. Please let me know if something is going wrong here.

Comment: your hardware is probably not fast enough to support videos in higer resolution. What does the taskmanger tell you regarding CPU / GPU / RAM?

Comment: I can observe GPU is 60% free , CPU is 40% and ram 55% free

Comment: there might be further limitation, eventually your maxing out your hardware decoder  or has short bursts in GPU usage that slow down you machine